# Customize tqdm bar in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, tqdm

I'm trying to change the display of `10000.000000001317/10000` to only two decimals.

```
Finished: 100%|████████████████████████████| 10000.000000001317/10000 [00:01<00:00, 9330.68it/s]
```

This is my code right now;

```
def create_dataframe(size):    
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    pbar = tqdm(total=size)
    #Increment is equal to the total number of records to be generated divided by the fields to be created
        #divided by total (this being the necessary iterations for each field)
    increment = size / 5 / size
    df["ID"] = range(size)
    pbar.set_description("Generating Names")
    df["Name"], _ = zip(*[(fake.name(), pbar.update(increment)) for _ in range(size)])
    pbar.set_description("Generating Emails")
    df["Email"], _ = zip(*[(fake.free_email(), pbar.update(increment)) for _ in range(size)])
    pbar.set_description("Generating Addresses")
    df["Address"], _ = zip(*[(fake.address(), pbar.update(increment)) for _ in range(size)])
    pbar.set_description("Generating Phones")
    df["Phone"], _ = zip(*[(fake.phone_number(), pbar.update(increment)) for _ in range(size)])
    pbar.set_description("Generating Comments")
    df["Comment"], _ = zip(*[(fake.text(), pbar.update(increment)) for _ in range(size)])
    pbar.set_description("Finished")
    pbar.close()
    return df
```

According to the [docs](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#format_meter), or at least what I've understood, this would be the default formatting to the argument *bar_format*;

```
pbar = tqdm(total=size, bar_format='{desc}{percentage:3.0f}%|{bar}| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}<{remaining}, ''{rate_fmt}{postfix}]')
```

I tried:

1. Setting **.2f** in *n_ftm*, the output of this results in an error.

```
pbar = tqdm(total=size, bar_format='{desc}{percentage:3.0f}%|{bar}| {n_fmt:.2f}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}<{remaining}, ''{rate_fmt}{postfix}]')
```

2. Or formatting the set_description,

```
pbar.set_description("Finished: {:.2f}/{:.2f}".format(pbar.n, size))
```

This prints another **x/total** before the actual bar;

```
Finished: 10000.00/10000.00: 100%|██████████| 10000.000000001317/10000 [00:01<00:00, 9702.65it/s]
```

- Plus it would be ideal once the bar finished having `10000/10000` no decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify the number of floating points because `n_fmt` is a string. You can however pass `unit_scale=True`:

```
pbar = tqdm(total=size,
                bar_format='{desc}{percentage:3.0f}%|{bar}| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}<{remaining}, ''{rate_fmt}{postfix}]',
                unit_scale=True)
```

According to the doc:

> If 1 or True, the number of iterations will be reduced/scaled
> automatically and a metric prefix following the
> International System of Units standard will be added
> (kilo, mega, etc.)

You'll get the following output for `size=10000`:

```
Finished: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10.0k/10.0k [00:03<00:00, 3.31kit/s]
```